# Javascript function not defined within document.ready jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scope, anonymous-function

I've included jquery in my script and am now trying to make a jquery version of this upload progress bar script: http://www.ultramegatech.com/2008/12/creating-upload-progress-bar-php/

Here's my attempt:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function startProgress(uid) {
        console.log("starting progress");
        setTimeout('getProgress("' + uid + '")', 500);
        //some more stuff
    }

    function getProgress(uid) {
        console.log("getting progress");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'upload_getprogress.php?uid=' + uid,
            success: function (msg) {
                progress = msg;
                setTimeout('getProgress("' + uid + '")', 100);
                // do some more stuff
            }

        });
    }

    $('#upload').submit(function () {
        startProgress('<?php echo $uid; ?>');
    });
});
```

But I'm getting this error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: getProgress is not defined`

How is that?

I tried to put the functions outside of `document.ready()`, but it didn't help. I even went and defined `getProgress` at the beginning of the inside of `startProgress` but it doesn't seem to recognize the function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: there is the error of setTimeout function syntax so correct that syntax it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't been able to double-check, but I'm guessing it's because of the scope of the submit callback. Try something along these lines;

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#upload').submit(function(){ window.startProgress('<?php echo $uid; ?>'); });
});

var startProgress = function(uid) {
       console.log("starting progress");
       setTimeout('getProgress("' + uid + '")', 500);
       //some more stuff
};

var getProgress = function(uid) {
    console.log("getting progress");
    $.ajax({  type: "GET", 
        url: 'upload_getprogress.php?uid=' + uid, 
        success: function(msg) {   
            progress = msg;
            setTimeout('getProgress("' + uid + '")', 100);
                    // do some more stuff
        }

    });
};

window.startProgress = startProgress;
window.getProgress = getProgress;
```

Comment: You don't need to define the functions as variables and then later define `window.function = function`, but other than that this should do the trick, so +1 :)

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. But what's the reason that my code wasn't working? Earlier, I did try to keep the functions outside of `document.ready()` and leave the `$('#upload').submit()` code inside, but even that didn't work. how did simply changing the definition of the functions to `var = function()` make all the difference?

Answer (score 3):

`getProgress()` is defined within the scope of the callback to `document.ready()`. If you pass a string argument to `setTimeout()` this is evaluated in the global scope. So you method is not visible from there.

You could change your code, to use an anonymous function like this:

```
 setTimeout( function() {
   getProgress( uid); 
 }
 , 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use the setTimeout function like
`setTimeout('getProgress("' + uid + '")',500)`,

you must put the function `getProgress` in global scope , 
if you use setTimeout function like `setTimeout( getProgress(uid),500)`,

you can define the function getProgress inside jQuery ready function

Answer (score 0):

Please use:

```
setTimeout(function() { getProgress( uid ); }, 500 )
```

That should work fine.

Comment: That would call getProgress with a literal string...
`getProgress("' + uid + '");`

Answer (score -1):

`function getProgress(uid)` is defined inside `$(document).ready()` so that it is in the private scope not in global scope. So to use it, just move it to global.